# Matrix field within safecracker form : new row opening blank page

Tags: matrix, safecracker

EE 2.5.2
Matrix 2.5.5

When you hit the add new row + button in the Matrix field within a safecracker form it opens a new blank page. The new row is added successfully but I can't work out why it is opening a blank page as well.

Comment: Are this in the Control Panel? Do you have a screenshot of your Matrix field?

Comment: Not in the control panel, no. It's a safecracker form on the front-end.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any errors in the console? It's usually the case that jQuery is being included twice on the same page. Be sure to use the include_jquery="no" parameter and have your own jQuery included before any Safecracker code.

Comment: No errors in the console and only one copy of jQuery loaded. Have just set include_jquery="no" in the safecraker form and have jQuery loading in the Head.